# Rerunning ARM template cause error

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have a very simple ARM template which spins up an app service plan and a website. When I delete plan or resource group it works fine and creates new plan and website. Following is the template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "environment": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "comments": "The environment to suffix to distinguish resources in different groups"
      }
      "allowedValues": ["Test","Uat","Stage"]
    }, 
    "planName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
 /*Other Parameters*/
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "planNameFull": /*expression*/,
    "siteTestNameFull": /*expression*/,
    "appDomainName": /*expression*/    
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "comments": "Application Plan (Serverfarm)",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "sku": {
        "name": "S1",
        "tier": "Standard",
        "Size": "S1",
        "family": "S",
        "capacity": "1"
      },
      "kind": "app",
      "name": "[variables('planNameFull')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('planNameFull'))]": "empty",
        "displayName": "[variables('planNameFull')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('planNameFull')]",
        "workerTierName": null,
        "adminSiteName": null,
        "hostingEnvironmentProfile": null,
        "perSiteScaling": false,
        "reserved": false,
        "targetWorkerCount": 0,
        "targetWorkerSizeId": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "comments": "Test Web Site",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "kind": "app",
      "name": "[variables('siteTestNameFull')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('planNameFull'))]": "empty",
        "displayName": "[variables('siteTestNameFull')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "clientAffinityEnabled": true,
        "enabled": true,
        "hostNameSslStates": [
          {
            "name:": "[concat(variables('siteTestNameFull') ,'.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "sslState": "Disabled",
            "hostType": "Standard"
          },
          {
            "name:": "[concat(variables('siteTestNameFull') ,'scm.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "sslState": "Disabled",
            "hostType": "Repository"
          }
        ],
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms',variables('planNameFull'))]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [ "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms',variables('planNameFull'))]" ],
      "resources": [
        {
          "comments": "Test Web Site Config.",
          "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
          "name": "[concat(variables('siteTestNameFull'),'/web')]",
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "tags": {
            "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('planNameFull'))]": "empty",
            "description": "[concat('Moula ', variables('siteTestNameFull'),' Settings')]",
            "displayName": "[concat(variables('siteTestNameFull'),' App Settings')]"
          },
          "properties": {
            "numberOfWorkers": 1,
            "defaultDocuments": [ "index.html" ],
            "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.7",
            "publishingUsername": "[parameters('webPublishingUser')]",
            "publishingPassword": "[parameters('webPublishingPwd')]",
            "siteAuthSettings": { "isAadAutoProvisioned": false },
            "ipSecurityRestrictions": [
              {
                "ipAddress": "115.xx.xxx.27",
                "subnetMask": null
              },
              {
                "ipAddress": "34.xxx.xx.90",
                "subnetMask": null
              }
            ],
            "appSettings": {
              "WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE": "[parameters('websiteTimezone')]",
              "WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES": "[parameters('testCertificate')]"
            },
            "use32BitWorkerProcess": false,
            "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
            "virtualApplications": [
              {
                "virtualPath": "/",
                "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
                "preloadEnabled": false,
                "vitualDirectories": null
              }
            ],
            "loadBalancingRules": [ "LeastRequests" ]
          },
          "dependsOn": [ "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites',variables('siteTestNameFull'))]" ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "planId": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('planNameFull'))]"
    },
    "TestAppId": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites',variables('siteTestNameFull'))]"
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that I want to run this template as VSTS build pipeline step. When I try to run template again without making any changes, it causes following error always:

```
Template deployment returned the following errors:
1:09:17 PM - Resource Microsoft.Web/sites 'TestWebsite' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "There was an unexpected InternalServerError.  Please try again later.  x-ms-correlation-request-id: 8cd06d54-vvvv-wwww-xxxx-5e55029fc640"
  }
}'
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you consistently getting the same error when deploying your ARM Template with VSTS?

Comment: @juvchan yes, the correlation id changes but otherwise for all 3-4 templates I tried end up same. Other templates were more complex (sites/configs/custom-domains etc). So I tried with this relatively simple one.

Comment: can you share the real error? You can get it using Azure monitor

Comment: This is what Monitor says: `af5ca351-e3f6-400c-9a09-cbb005afd9b2 | Microsoft.Resources/deployments/write | Failed | Error | 2018-02-28T02:37:20.3176865Z`

Comment: Does this Web App (M**************Nz) still exist, or was it since deleted?

Comment: For some reason the "name" property for each of the elements in hostNameSslStates collection is set to null in the API request. That is what is causing the error. Not sure why the template does not set it correctly, but you can just remove the entire hostNameSslStates collection from the template as it is not necessary when creating or updating a site.

Comment: @DavidEbbo, that one is deleted. I can run the template again or the one I sent you (correlation id) is there.

Comment: @RuslanY I will try with removing `hostNameSslStates` section.

Comment: Ruslan's suggestion will take care of the issue

Comment: @DavidEbbo yes that made it work!

Comment: thanks @RuslanY, removing hostNameSslStates section made it work!

Comment: removing hostNameSslStates did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons for this type of error. [This is the official documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting).

- Downtime of either the service you're deploying to in the region you're deploying to.
- Downtime of Azure DevOps itself.
- The resource type you're trying to deploy isn't yet available in that region.

Comment: In my occation I was referencing an existing Azure Container Registry, but the ARM template defined that in Norway East, where ACR isn't yet available, so I had to modify the template to add another parameter acrLocation.